# Report by Product Variations in Woocommerce using phpmyadmin for a SPECIFIC product

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

I want to generate a query in phpmyadmin that will give me a report of how many of a particular product (variation) that have been ordered. To get the basic report of any variation that has been ordered, I can run:

```
SELECT `meta_value`, COUNT(*) FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'pa_size' GROUP BY `meta_value`
```

This works (for now). But when I have another product later on, I want to be able to run a similar query that will limit my results to one particular product (the unique field for this is "_product_id", which is also in the same meta_key column as the pa_size). So basically I want a query: "output all the variations as a list AND do so for this particular product only."

Here are some sample lines that show these product variations together:

[image: sample spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old now, and you probably figured it out by now... but man, I needed this too and the query is just far too complex... then I remembered the new WooCommerce Admin dashboard plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-admin/

This has the exact thing I needed. Reporting on a product level broken out by variation.[image]

Hope that helps someone else who may come across this thread!